# C - display char as hex

Tags: c, char, hex, printf

I want to print the ASCII code of a char in hex; for example, for

```
char a = 0xA5;
```

I want to print `A5` on the console. Here is what I have tried:

```
char a = 0xA5;
printf("%02X", a);
```

but i get `FFFFFFA5`. How could I solve this?

Comment: `"%02hhX"` should do it on a C99 or later compiler. Certainly a dupe.

Comment: @chux Thanks it works!

Answer (score 2):

Cast the value to `unsigned char`, then cast again to `unsigned int` to be printed via `%X`.

```
char a = 0xA5;
printf("%02X", (unsigned int)(unsigned char)a);
```

Note that conversion to signed integer which is not capable to store original value is implementation-defined, but conversion to unsigned integer is defined, according to [N1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) 6.3.1.3

Comment: `(unsigned int)` not needed. C11 §6.5.2.2 6 "the behavior is undefined, except for the following cases: — one promoted type is a signed integer type, the other promoted type is the corresponding unsigned integer type, and the value is representable in both types"

Comment: Yes - sure.  case 1: `char` is signed.  `(unsigned char)a` and fits in `int`.  Per " §6.5.2.2 6", applies as it will also fit in `unsigned`. (might want to read the whole paragraph.  case 2: `char` is signed.  `(unsigned char)a` and does not fits in `int` but `unsigned`.  No problem with `%X`. case 3  `char` is unsigned and  and fits in `int`.  - goes like case 1.  case 4: `char` is unsigned and fits in `unsigned`. Obviously no issue.  Case 1 is likely the only one that may not convince you.  If not, maybe post a question?  It all centers on §6.5.2.2 6

Comment: @chux some people argue that `%X` is undefined unless the type of the argument is exactly `unsigned int`. After all , the standard does actually say that.  (My view is the standard is defective and you should be able to use `unsigned char` here)

Comment: Yes it does say that - in one part.  The standard is 600+ pages and it must be taken as a whole.  "type of the argument is exactly unsigned int" is problematic as the narrow arguments undergo the usual promotions.  C11 §6.5.2.2 6  details an exception allowing a promoted value that is representable in both `int` and `unsigned` to behave the same, whether `"%d"`, `"%X"`, `"%o"`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The "problem" is called sign extension -- parameteres are passed as int by default so a char would be converted to int and in the process the sign extension would means that the extra f are added -- make the char unsigned like this

```
unsigned char a = 0xA5;
printf("%02X", a);
```

and the compiler will understand how to treat your data.